# Browserify DataTables

Tags: javascript, datatables, browserify

I tried following the instructions at [NPM packages - DataTables](https://www.datatables.net/download/npm) but I still can't get it to bundle with Browserify.

Here is my minimal, complete, and verifiable example:

### app.js

```
'use strict'

var $ = require('jquery')
var dt = require('datatables.net-dt')()

$(document.getElementById('table')).DataTable()
```

### Output of `npm list`

```
foo@1.0.0 /home/RinkAttendant6/www/foo
├─┬ datatables.net@1.10.10
│ └── jquery@2.1.4
└── datatables.net-dt@1.5.2
```

### Output of `browserify app.js -o bundle.js`

```
Error: Cannot find module 'datatables.net-dt' from '/home/RinkAttendant6/www/foo'
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:46:17
    at process (/usr/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:173:43)
    at ondir (/usr/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:188:17)
    at load (/usr/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:69:43)
    at onex (/usr/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:92:31)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:22:47
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:82:15)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried adding browserify-shim?

Comment: @RajuBera No. Is there any reason I need browserify-shim for things that are CommonJS compatible?

Comment: You are right, if it's commonJs module we don't need of browserify-shim.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the package vendor, the `datatables.net` package should be used instead of `datatables.net-dt` unless Bootstrap or Foundation is used.

Refer to https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables/issues/434#issuecomment-161278064

> Instead use:
>
> ```
> var dt = require('datatables.net')()
> ```
>
> The reason for this is that the datatables.net-dt package does not contain a Javascript file - it doesn't need one - it contains only CSS (it should actually contain a couple of images as well, that will be corrected in 1.10.11).
>
> No Javascript file is required there since the DataTables defaults are suitable for DataTables styling. The same is not the case for Bootstrap, etc.

Answer (score 4):

Using another recommendation within that github issue thread worked for me.

See: https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables/issues/434#issuecomment-113286718

```
var DataTable = require('datatables.net')()

$.fn.DataTable = DataTable
```

That code worked with or without a browserify-shim entry for datatables.

Comment: had the same issue when I tried to use datatable with gulp, browserify in a laravel project and above solution fixed the issue. Thanks for saving my day !